# java images with alpha channel without using buffered image

Tags: java, image, alpha

im drawing a bunch of tiles on a `Canvas`, these tiles are represented by either `Image`s or `BufferedImage`s.

i noticed that im getting millisecond draws with `Image`s but what i start using `BufferedImage`s for the tiles the frame time sky rockets to above 20ms.

```
BufferedImage buffered = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(fileName);
```

Both of these images support alpha channels.  I would like to start using alpha capable `Image`'s for intermediary buffers.  However i havent found a place in the jdk that can generate them besides this Toolkit call to create one from a file.

Basically does anyone know how to create a blank Image (not BufferedImage) from scratch that can support alpha?

Comment: BufferedImage is an Image.  Image is an abstract class and the only two subclasses in the standard Java library are BufferedImage and VolatileImage (which you probably don't want to use).  The real question is why does drawing happen faster with images loaded from a Toolkit?  Are you writing an Applet?  If not, consider using a JComponent instead of a Canvas object.  The AWT library is usually slower than its Swing counterpart.

Comment: How are you creating your buffered images? Which type are they?

Comment: @Pace: there are other subclasses of `java.awt.Image`, i.e. `sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage` which you get when you use the Toolkit methods to create an image and these images happen to paint much faster than BufferedImage objects for some reason.

Comment: @basszero, im using the two lines of code above. The first line creates a BufferedImage from a file, and the second creates a non-BufferedImage from that same file.

@Pace, actually i found in tests that the AWT library is faster for my uses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

```
// Create a empty BufferedImage which supports alpha
// It will be just as fast a Toolkit image
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Some background:

It all comes down to the TYPE of BufferedImage you're using. BufferedImage offers a constructor in which you can specifiy the TYPE (INT_ARGB, 4BYTE_ARGB, etc). When using ImageIO, you do not have control over the type that gets used in construction of the BufferedImage. ImageIO uses type "0" which is custom. The TYPE governs how the image data is stored/accessed in memory which plays heavily into how the image is drawn/copied/blitted to the screen (or other image).

I created a simple test based on your code and the BufferedImage always renders VERY slowly. I create a second BufferedImage with TYPE_INT_ARGB and copied the first BufferedImage (from ImageIO) into it. This TYPE_INT_ARGB BufferedImage renders at the same speed as the Toolkit image.

Comment: Basically does anyone know how to create a blank Image (not BufferedImage) from scratch that can support alpha?

Comment: Why the non-BufferedImage requirement? If you read the rest of my response you will learn that a INT_ARGB BufferedImage is just as fast as the Toolkit image

Comment: wow your right, i tried to find out why this was, but the only difference i can find is that the IMageIO buffered image uses a image type of 0, or CUSTOM, so i guess it loops and paints each pixel individually. sorry about the curt response.

Comment: I add more to it, but I'm not sure exactly how you want it too read. Seems like all of the info is there to me.

Comment: nah i just couldnt vote you up, until you edited it.  its all there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the old ImageConsumer/ImageProducer API to create Image objects with any content you want.

This will create an Image object from ARGB pixels in the `pix` array with the given width and height:

```
public static Image createImage( int width, int height, int[] pix )
{
    return createImage( width, height, pix, 0, width );
}

public static Image createImage( int width, int height, int[] pix, int offs, int scan )
{
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    ImageProducer source = new MemoryImageSource( width, height, pix, offs, scan );
    return toolkit.createImage( source );
}
```

Comment: never used this before, will give it a whirl.  it looks promising, just never used that API before.